# Can I rsync from Putty on windows to my Cent OS server?

Tags: windows, centos, rsync, putty

I'm a bit new to the command line and UNIX but am finding it hugely useful. Is it possible for me to rsync from putty on my windows 7 machine to my virtual server?

If not what are my other command line options? I just want to update my cms scripts without having to SFTP into each website account with Filezilla. A nice rsync command would suit me better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cygwin is a way to run a Linux-like environment on window. Among other things it provides a rsync binary.

http://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: So I guess the question is now can I SSH with Cygwin? I'm guessing I can.

Comment: Ok I think I found it http://inside.mines.edu/~gmurray/HowTo/sshNotes.html

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [cwRsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650), a packaging of rsync for Windows. PuTTY by itself does not provide rsync.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Deltacopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) which is a windows implementation of rsync. The package contains just what you need to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I use `rsync` in Cygwin on Win-XP to transfer files to and from a Linux virtual server. If your Centos server has a name which Windows 7 understands, it might be as simple as

```
rsync -avz --progress ~/sortdata/ root@centos:/var/www/sort/
```

It's not necessary to use Putty - that would probably mean logging into the Centos server and doing the `rsync` in the opposite direction.

BTW, keep using that command-line -- it gets easier with practice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had been searching for rsync for windows or a similar solution, turns out that Filezilla is much more comfortable to use, so you don't need rsync

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Rsync is versatile command-line automatible tool that is able to retransfer only changed files and even it is capable to only transfer changes in big files without retransferring the entire file by using its praised delta-transfer algorithm. It's often used for automated backups and synchronization. FileZilla AFAIK does only allow interactive use and provides no support for automation or efficient delta-transfer, so can't be used for automated backups. It's entirely different tool for different purposes. so your suggestion doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: yep you're right, "it is capable to only transfer changes in big files" filezilla doesn't have that capability as far as I know, but today it so happened that I desperately needed rsync, but apparently there's no straight-forward way to install rsync on windows, this shouldn't bee the case but it is